# PHP to UML class Diagrams

Tags: php, android, uml

Just wanted to know if there is any way i can create class Diagram from PHP code. I have PHP code 
accepting POST data from Android(HTTP ) and storing that Data in a MySql database.how do i represent it, i created a class diagram of my android code using ObjectAid plugin for Eclipse. but cannot figure out how to represent PHPMYSql in a class diagram. Tried Enterprise Architect , Didn't work for me.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for this as well. In my search I did find phuml.

https://github.com/jakobwesthoff/phuml

It is currently not being developed on and I am unsure on how good the results are (the test I've run is on a codebase that is quite large and that I do not know myself).

However, it is quite easy to work with. 
Requires graphviz installed.

apt-get graphviz if you're on linux.

The bad part of it is that you get the UML as img, or pdf. If you generate a PDF it is searchable, but I still haven't figured out a way to make it editable as UML in any uml diagram application.

Supported file formats to export to: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html

Comment: @Yousafzai I ended up using doxygen. It creates javadocs-styled documentation. with flowcharts for call and caller functions. Worked pretty well in my case. http://www.doxygen.nl/

Answer (score 0):

The set of tools (and their capabilities) that can do this automagically for you is limited. `UML` models are usually created manually, before a code is written.

From the `UML` perspective there is no difference between `PHP` Object-Oriented code and `Android` Object-Oriented code and `MySQL` tables are just classes without operations.

Although you may be lucky in partially automating the model creation through reverse-engineering, to make it readable and emphasize parts that are important through diagrams with different level of detail, you'll have to involve a manual work.

For an overview of what can `UML` do for you, walk through Kirill Fakhroutdinov's online book [uml-diagrams.org: UML Diagrams Examples](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html)

Comment: @Yousafzai Enterprise Architect can be helpful in automatic creation of UML class diagrams through reverse engineering of your `PHP`, `Java`, `MySQL` code. See [Sparx Systems: Database Engineering → Import Database Schema](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/database_engineering/importdatabaseschemafromod.html) and [Sparx Systems: Software Engineering → Importing Source Code](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/software_engineering/reverseengineersourcecode.html). If you find my answer useful you can accept it if nothing better shows up

Comment: Thanks i will have a look